# how to check if node is visible in intersectionObserver api

Tags: javascript, html, dom, viewport, intersection-observer

given [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) like this:

```
const observeVisibility = intersectionMargin => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        nodes => {
            if (nodes[0].isIntersecting) {
                /* is really in viewport? */
                this.observer.disconnect();
            }
        },
        { rootMargin: intersectionMargin }
    );

    observer.observe(...);
};
```

How to check whether the node itself is actually in viewport or it's just the intersectionMargin that caused observer to be called?

Answer (score 0):

The [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) will fire [immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214116/intersectionobserver-callback-firing-immediately-on-page-load/53385264?noredirect=1#comment93646526_53385264) on load.  After that, your callback passed to `IntersectionObserver` will be called when `isIntersecting` changes or when the `intersectionRatio` crosses one of your configured `threshold`s.

As you can see, the callback gets the list of entries and then it is up to you to do what you want.

```
//assuming 'threshold' is defined in scope

nodes => {
  nodes.forEach(entry => {
    const { isIntersecting, intersectionRatio } = entry;

    if (Array.isArray(threshold)) {
      threshold = threshold[threshold.length - 1];
   }

    if (isIntersecting || intersectionRatio >= threshold) {
      this.observer.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```