# IntersectionObserver callback firing immediately on page load

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

I'm very new to the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), and I've been experimenting with this code:

```
let target = document.querySelector('.lazy-load');

let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

observer.observe(target);

function callback() {
    console.log('observer triggered.');
}
```

This seems to work as it should, and `callback()` is called whenever `.lazy-load` element enters the viewport, but `callback()` also fires once when the page is initially loaded, which triggers `console.log('observer triggered.');

Is there a reason for this callback to be triggered when the page loads? Or is there a mistake in how I'm implementing this?

**Edit: Altering the code to the below still fires the callback at page load.**

```
let target = document.querySelector('.lazy-load');

let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0
}

let callback = function(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {

        console.log('observer triggered.');

    });
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

observer.observe(target);
```

Comment: I have a similar problem but with a threshold of 1.. So answers here don't apply

Answer (score 82, accepted):

That is the default behaviour.  When you instantiate an instance of the IntersectionObserver, the `callback` will be fired.

It is recommended to guard against this case.

```
entries.forEach(entry => {
  if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
    entry.target.classList.add('in-viewport');
  } else {
    entry.target.classList.remove('in-viewport');
  }
});
```

Also I found this article as well as the docs to be very helpful, specifically about the `intersectionRatio` or `isIntersecting` properties on the IntersectionObserverEntry.

· https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/deferring-lazy-loading-intersection-observer-api/

· https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver

· https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think is better to rely on `isIntersecting` because sometimes I've seen some cases where `intersectingRatio` was zero but `isIntersecting` was true ---which in my case was the correct behaviour.

Comment: @zenw0lf Great point!  That is what I do here...

https://github.com/snewcomer/intersection-observer-admin/blob/28b25180c231b09c61239b6440e8f48a345ea808/src/index.ts#L229

Comment: Sad that you can't use the case when it's NOT intersecting to .unobserve() the element. Only with some ugly mutators that mark if the element has already been in the viewport

Comment: ' When you instantiate an instance of the IntersectionObserver, the callback will be fired'. My understanding is that the first time you call the observe method of the new IntersectionObserver then that invokes the callback.  If you have a button to just invoke the observe method then that should asynchronously invoke the IntersectionObserver.

Comment: Hello, @snewcomer could you take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75204977/intersectionobserver-to-create-a-lazy-load-images-with-data-srcset-and-imagekit

Answer (score 4):

as easy as it sounds I was able to fix the issue by

1. adding a threshold comparison condition
2. adding a slight delay for initialization of observer

```js
    const options = {
      threshold: 1.0,
    };

      setTimeout(() => {
        observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
          console.log("OBSERVER TRIGGERED 1");

          if (
            entry &&
            entry.isIntersecting &&
            entry.intersectionRatio >= options.threshold
          ) {
            console.log("OBSERVER TRIGGERED 2");
          }
        }, options);

        observer.observe(observerRef.value);
      }, 2000);
```

I would also suggest **temporary** changing the background color for observable element to something like:

```css
.observer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

and doing the page refresh. This way your might actually see the red background flashing on your screen hence triggering the event.

Now, before you throw tomatoes at me - in my case - I have a dozen of videos on the webpage. The video HTML elements are not "expanded" right away, because browser needs to download information about the poster images. Hence the page was loaded but vides were still loading one by one.. Adding a slight delay fixed the issue so the browser had time to expand the video contents.

Comment: Such a great point to give it a red background-color.

Answer (score 2):

I know its been a few years since this question was asked, but I was in a similar situation recently when working with a react component.

I was applying an intersection observer on a `div`, which I wanted to run only when the div was crossed while scrolling, but not on page load.

The general code I used to ignore the initial observer call was:

```
function Component() {
  const ref = useRef();
  const firstCallImminent = useRef(true);

  // This will run the callback once the component renders.
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      () => {
        if (!firstCallImminent.current) {
          // Your logic here
        } else {
          firstCallImminent.current = false;
        }
      },
      {
        root: null,
        threshold: 0,
      }
    );
    observer.observe(ref.current);

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
      firstCallImminent.current = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref}>...</div>;
}
```

The way this code works is this:

1. The first time the `Component` renders, it creates 2 `ref`s. One of them is a reference to the `div` of the returned jsx, the other (`firstCallImminent`) is used to track if the execution of the observer callback will be its initial execution. `firstCallImminent` will be initialized to `true`.
2. Next, the useEffect callback will run to create a new intersection observer, with the callback:

```js
() => {
  if (!firstCallImminent.current) {
    // Your logic here
  } else {
    firstCallImminent.current = false;
  }
}
```

In this callback, your logic will only run if the value of `firstCallImminent.current` is `false`. However, on the loading of this component, we had set it to be `true`. This means that the moment the observer begins observation (`observer.observe(ref.current)`), the first run of the callback will **not** execute your logic, and set the value of `firstCallImminent.current` to `false` instead.

Now, when the callback is run the *next time*, your logic will run.

3. Lastly, we use a cleanup function:

```js
() => {
    observer.disconnect();
    firstCallImminent.current = true;
  }
```

Say that for whatever reason, the useEffect callback needs to run again (maybe your logic had some stateful dependencies?). In that case, we would want that the previous observer disconnects.

In my case, I also wanted that when a new observer is made and applied, *its* callback should also omit the first execution of the callback, so, I also reset the value of `firstCallImminent.current` to `true`, so as to repeat the above process of skipping the first (or, in this case, next) call of the intersection observer's callback.

So.. this was the way I did this in React. In plain HTML, perhaps such a modification would work?:

```js
let target = document.querySelector('.lazy-load');

let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0
}

let firstCallImminent = true;

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

observer.observe(target);

function callback() {
    if(!firstCallImminent)
        console.log('observer triggered.');
    else
        firstCallImminent = false;
}
```